# How do I inverse level progression and make new stats?

Tags: rpg, progression, rpg-maker-mv

I'm trying to make something like [Vampire: Dark Ages](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Ages:_Vampire) in RPG Maker MV, but the problem is that I need new stats and a reverse level progression, as long as you start at 12nd generation (like the "level 1" in the rest of the games) and the next "level" is 11st generation.

It should have this stats:

- Strenght
- Dexterity
- Resistance
- Charisma
- Manipulation
- Appearence
- Perception
- Intelligence
- Wits

This would only change by "buying abilities" with Job Points, and they determinate most of actions in the game. The only that would change would be the "Vitae Points", that act as Magic Points or Mana Points. When you have higher generation (low level), you have less Vitae/Blood points than if you have lower generation (high level).

How can I make this work? There's some plugin for this?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you really want, you need to give a better explanation of what you want to achieve. Nonetheless, since you already confirmed that you want a complete rewrite of the status of the characters at least of already know that you would need to write a plugin for your status and display, damage calculation and other stuff. This seems to be a big work only for the experienced.

Comment: If you say to spanish this: "This seems to be a big work only for the experienced" and add to it "No hay huevos" (more like "There's no balls", I don't know if this is the right way to translate it), be sure he/she is going to do it in any way. Also, I've solved part of the problem (and also learned javascript in one evening!).

Answer (score 1):

### **I was investigating and I've come to somekind of answer:**

> Is there some plugin for this?

Yes, there are plugins that can achieve this, more or less. I've used three: [Yanfly's Base Parameter Control](http://yanfly.moe/2016/03/25/yep-86-base-parameter-control/), this one is useful to set custom parameter calculations, [Yanlfy's Class Base Parameters](http://yanfly.moe/2016/04/24/yep-95-class-base-parameters/), this makes it easier to set your own way of developing your characters, and [Himeworks Parameter Tables](http://himeworks.com/2016/01/parameter-tables-mv/) allows you to create your own parameters.

> How can I make this work?

Well, in this case, there are two ways to make it work. The easiest is using the plugins mentioned earlier, and the other is using common events and [Yanfly's Actor Variables](http://yanfly.moe/2015/12/10/yep-41-actor-variables/). Using common events you can make a dice roller that executes every time you use some ability and define your own level up event. For example, I've made an event called "[Diablere](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Diablerie_(VTM))" and an ability to use it. It would check first if the ability has effect, and then it would check the effects of leveling up.